# XMLHttpRequest ReadyState always undefined

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm following the PHP/AJAX tutorials at w3schools, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock at square one. Every time I call this function, the readystate is always undefined.

```
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log("Using XMLHttpRequest");
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            console.log("Using ActiveXObject");
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xmlhttp.readystate);

        if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.status);
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change this line:

```
if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { ...
```

to this (via typo):

```
if (xmlhttp.readystate = 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { ...
```

Then it works, but it feels kind of like a "magic happens here" thing to be writing the code like this.

Comment: `xmlhttp.readystate = 4` (with single equals sign, assignment) assigns `4` to the `.readystate` property and is an expression that evaluates to `4`, which is a `truthy` value and thus passes the if check. So it might as well have been `if( true && xmlhttp.status == 200 )` or just `if( xmlhttp.status == 200)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JS is case sensitive. You need to check the `readyState` property, not the `readystate` property.

```
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.status);
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: In addition, `readyState` shouldn't ever be `undefined`.  It starts at zero when the object is created, so getting `undefined` is a pretty good sign of a typo.

Comment: @PaulButcher readyState returns `undefined` when status is any error code like `404` .