# Script Error when Readystate=4

Tags: javascript

```
if (document.getElementById("crystal_iframe").ReadyState == 4)
```

When the debugger encounter this line in InternetExplorer9 it's get the script error as "Permission Denied" what is the error in that line please help me to find out.

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: Based on the id of your element, `crystal_iframe`, I'm assuming this element is an iframe and you're attempting to detect when it finishes loading? If this is correct, check out the second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548984/detect-if-the-iframe-content-has-loaded-successfully

Comment: Don't you mean `.readyState`?

Comment: My problem solved thanks i use R in readyState

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest ReadyState always undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636612/xmlhttprequest-readystate-always-undefined)